# INSERT INTO NO funciona y el código no da error

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Intento arreglar un registro que lleva funcionando mas de 6 meses bien sin ningún error, y hace poco sin cuento alguno y sin tocar nada del código desde hace bastante tiempo, empezó dando error al guardar en la base de datos.

Es decir, el código tira bien y me guarda hasta un registro que lo tengo llamado como "log" que me informa si alguien se registra, pero el registro en sí no lo guarda, no me guarda los datos de username, email, etc... en la tabla "usuarios". Pero como bien digo, si me guarda los datos de acción, fecha y demás en la tabla logs. Si alguien me pudiese ayudar.

Código:

```
  
  if(!empty($_POST)){
  
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    
    $secret = '6LfdrSUaAAAAAGOZ41fjWCj-KleyyJ_7JWUg_ZDX';
    
    if(!$captcha){
 
      header ("Location: ../../index.php?nopass");
      exit();
      
      } else {
      
      $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captcha");
      
      $arr = json_decode($response, TRUE);
      
      if($arr['success'])
      {
        echo '<h2>Thanks</h2>';
        } else {
        echo '<h3>Error al comprobar Captcha </h3>';
        die();
      }
    }
  }
?>


<?php
require ('../../global.php');
    // Primero comprobamos que ning�n campo est� vac�o y que todos los campos existan.
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) &&
    isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password']) &&
    isset ($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
        // Si entramos es que todo se ha realizado correctamente

        $cifrado5 = md5($_POST['password']);
        $cifrado4 = sha1($cifrado5);
        $cifrado3 = md5($cifrado4);
        $cifrado2 = sha1($cifrado3);
        $cifrado1 = md5($cifrado2);
            $password = md5($cifrado1);
            $username = htmlentities($_POST['username']);
            $mail = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
            $fecha = date('d/m/y');
            $avatar = $username;
 
        $queEmp = "SELECT username FROM usuarios WHERE username='$username'";
        $resEmp = $link->query($queEmp) or die(mysqli_error());
        $totEmp = mysqli_num_rows($resEmp);
        if($totEmp > 0){
        header ("Location: ../../registro.php?usererror");
                            ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  location.href ="../../registro.php?usererror";
</script>
<?php
        exit();
        }

        $queEmp = "SELECT email FROM usuarios WHERE email='$mail'";
        $resEmp = $link->query($queEmp) or die(mysqli_error());
        $totEmp = mysqli_num_rows($resEmp);
        if($totEmp > 0){
        header ("Location: ../../registro.php?emailerror");
                            ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  location.href ="../../registro.php?emailerror";
</script>
<?php
        exit();
        }

        // Con esta sentencia SQL insertaremos los datos en la base de datos
        $link->query("INSERT INTO usuarios (username,password,email,fecha,avatar,ip)
        VALUES ('$username','$password','$mail','$fecha','https://www.habbo.es/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?direction=4&head_direction=2&action=&gesture=sml&size=m&user=".($avatar)."','$ip_actual')");

// Guardar acción en Logs si se ha iniciado sesión
$fecha_log = date("Y-m-d");
$accion = "Se ha registrado";
$enviar_log = "INSERT INTO logs (usuario,accion,fecha) values ('".$username."','".$accion."','".$fecha_log."')";
$link->query($enviar_log);
// Log guardado en Base de datos
        
        
        // Ahora comprobaremos que todo ha ido correctamente
        $my_error = mysqli_error($link);

        if(!empty($my_error)) {

            header ("Location: ../../registro.php?errordat");
                                ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  location.href ="../../registro.php?errordat";
</script>
<?php

        } else {
             header ("Location: ../../login.php?sucess");
                                 ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  location.href ="../../registro.php?sucess";
</script>
<?php

        }

    } else {

         header ("Location: ../../registro.php?errordb");
                             ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  location.href ="../../registro.php?errordb";
</script>
<?php

    }

?>
```

[image: Esta es la imagen de la base de datos y de la tabla en donde debería guardarse y no lo hace]

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Revisaste los logs de PHP? Si encuentras algo ahí, edita tu pregunta y añádelo

Comment: en la consulta de guardar el usuario no concatenas las variables con el string tal como lo haces en la consulta del log de abajo, intenta hacerlo igual a ver.

Comment: trata de poner el `ID` de la tabla en `int(11)` puede ser que tus registros ya superaron los 9 dígitos y eso no este guardando nada en el registro.

Comment: @Alfabravo hola, muchas gracias por tú respuesta, ¿a qué te refieres exactamente?

Comment: @Abdiel también lo he intentado y nada, no me deja.

Comment: @Daniel ¡Hola!, es un poco imposible ya que el último usuario registrado sería el 456 igualmente ya lo he hecho por si acaso y sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: PHP genera logs. Ahí se pueden ver errores que no se presentan en pantalla. Revisaste los logs?

Comment: @Alfabravo No, la verdad. ¿Me podrías decir como verlos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando programes piensa en todos los posibles errores, y escribe código para afrontarlos. Eso no ocurre precisamente en tu código de inserción, así que el mismo está fallando y no sabes el motivo.

Modificando esa parte del siguiente modo deberás saber lo que está ocurriendo:

```
// Con esta sentencia SQL insertaremos los datos en la base de datos
$sql="INSERT INTO usuarios (username,password,email,fecha,avatar,ip)
        VALUES ('$username','$password','$mail','$fecha','https://www.habbo.es/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?direction=4&head_direction=2&action=&gesture=sml&size=m&user=".($avatar)."','$ip_actual')";

#Controlamos lo que ocurra con la inserción
if ( $link->query($sql) && $link->affected_rows > 0 ) {       
    // Guardar acción en Logs si se ha iniciado sesión
    $fecha_log = date("Y-m-d");
    $accion = "Se ha registrado";
    $enviar_log = "INSERT INTO logs (usuario,accion,fecha) values ('".$username."','".$accion."','".$fecha_log."')";

    // Log guardado en Base de datos      
    if ($link->query($enviar_log)) {
        echo "Log guardado";        
    } else {
        printf("Error insertando log: %s",$link->error);
    }

} else {
    #Luego puedes incorporar esto a tus manejos de error
    printf("Error insertando registro: %s",$link->error);
}
```

Aquí simplemente he impreso en pantalla los motivos de error o mensajes de éxito según el caso. Adapta tú lo que quieras en tus redirecciones y demás. Si fuera tú yo no mezclaría código PHP/Javascript, ni me metería en lío de redirecciones, haciendo todo esto vía Ajax, pero esto supondría reformas más profundas en el código. Quizá más adelante te decidas por ese estilo, todo dependerá del contexto y de tus posibilidades.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Gracias a este código pude solucionarlo, al parecer en la tabla tenía algunas que por defecto no tenían ningún valor y no me lo guardaba por ese motivo. ¡Gracias de nuevo!. Pero, ¿no es un poco raro que antes no diera y ahora sí?